# In python what is the procedure to import a module which takes sys.argv arguments to run?

Tags: python, import, module

I try to import a module `a.py` in module `b.py`.

The module `a.py` takes `sys.argv` command line arguments to run.

So now when I import it in `b.py` and execute `b.py` where would I provide the `sys.argv` arguments required by the `a.py` module?

For example:

**a.py**

```
import sys
x = sys.argv[1]
print x
```

**b.py**

```
from a import *
print x
```

So now where would I provide the value of `x`?

Comment: Hmm...did you try run your code and check the output?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to pass an argument to b.py and then pass it to a.py.

Answer (score 0):

argv is filled by command line parameter [python module sys](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

calling this:  `python b.py hello` will print `hello`